# Debugging a Tutorial Hadoop Pipes-Project

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working through this [tutorial](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop)
and got to the very last part (with some small changes).
Now I am stuck with an error message I can't make sense of.

```
damian@damian-ThinkPad-T61:~/hadoop-1.1.2$ bin/hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input dft1 -output dft1-out -program bin/word_count

13/06/09 20:17:01 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/06/09 20:17:01 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/06/09 20:17:01 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/06/09 20:17:01 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating word_count in /tmp/hadoop-damian/mapred/local/archive/7642618178782392982_1522484642_696507214/filebin-work-1867423021697266227 with rwxr-xr-x
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/word_count as /tmp/hadoop-damian/mapred/local/archive/7642618178782392982_1522484642_696507214/filebin/word_count
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/word_count as /tmp/hadoop-damian/mapred/local/archive/7642618178782392982_1522484642_696507214/filebin/word_count
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@4200d3
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/06/09 20:17:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/06/09 20:17:02 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:214)
13/06/09 20:17:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/09 20:17:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/06/09 20:17:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
13/06/09 20:17:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

Does anyone see where the error hides? What is a straightforward way for debugging Hadoop Pipes programs?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the tutorial code run without any changes?

Comment: I did not change the code inside word_count.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

The exception :

```
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:103)
```

Is caused by the following lines in the source:

```
//Add token to the environment if security is enabled
Token<JobTokenIdentifier> jobToken = TokenCache.getJobToken(conf
    .getCredentials());
// This password is used as shared secret key between this application and
// child pipes process
byte[]  password = jobToken.getPassword();
```

The actual NPE is throw in the final line as `jobToken` is null.

As you're using local mode (local job tracker and local file system), i'm not sure that security should be 'enabled' - do you have either of the following properties configured in your core-site.xml, or hdfs-site.xml coniguration files (if so, what are their values):

- hadoop.security.authentication
- hadoop.security.authorization

Comment: Hi Chris, I searched the xmls in the folder and found several of them: in src/test/hdfs-site.xml hadoop.security.authentication is set to simple. In src/test/core-site.xml again  hadoop.security.authentication is set to simple. Inside share/hadoop/templates/conf/core-site.xml and src/packages/template/conf/core-site.xml the values are ${SECURITY_TYPE} and ${SECURITY}.

Comment: I played around replacing ${SECURITY_TYPE} and ${SECURITY} in the latter two xmls by 'simple'. This did not change the message I receive.

Comment: What's the value of the files in `/home/hadoop/hadoop/conf`? - or where ever the hadoop script is run from?

Comment: They are both empty like this: damian@damian-ThinkPad-T61:~/hadoop-1.1.2$ bin/hadoop fs -text ./conf/hdfs-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because your cluster is running in local mode. Do you have the following property in your `mapred-site.xml` file?

```
 <property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
   <description>
    Let the MapReduce jobs run with the yarn framework.
   </description>
 </property>
```

If you don't have this property, your cluster, by default, will run in local mode. I used to have exactly the same problem in local mode. After I add this property, the cluster will run in distributed mode and the problem will be gone.

HTH,

Shumin